# Use Cast() function in where clause - T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, casting, decimal

I am trying to use a CAST() function in the where clause of a query. Basically I have a FieldA in TableA that is typed as Decimal(10,0), and a FieldB in TableB that is typed as CHAR, and I would like to join the two tables on the conditions that Fields A and B are identical.

I have tried a simple

```
select FieldA , FieldB from tableA left join tableB 
on cast(FieldB as decimal(10,0))= FieldA
```

But it returns an error

> character non admitted in the CAST clause

EDIT this was a bad translation from french, the right translation seems to be

> invalid character value for cast specification

(thx Alex K)

I then tried to do something like

```
select tableA.fieldA, tableC.fieldC
from tableA left join
(select cast(fieldB as decimal(10,0)) fieldC from tableB)
as tableC on fieldC=fieldA
```

But I have the same error being returned

I am really not an expert in SQL and basically just use a few SELECTs here and there, tried to look around for similar problems but can't see an answer that matches my problem.

Anyone have an idea ? Thanks

Comment: I've never seen that error message before, but I can only guess 1)it was translated from a non-English language and 2)you have a comma where it expects a decimal point or vice versa in FieldB

Comment: Can you paste the exact error massage in here? (Even if it is not english) Include all numbers that might be in there too.

Comment: For performance reasons, your approach would not be very scalable. It'd be better having an additional column containing the `CAST` values stored in the DB. 

Generally speaking, try and avoid using functions in `JOIN`s and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Since there are multiple tables in the query, I believe that the `cast()` should specify the `table.field`. Something like this `cast(tableB.FieldB as decimal(10,0))`. I also think that casting from a `decimal` to `char` is a better way to go; `cast(tableA.FieldA as CHAR(100))`.

Comment: In addition, is there a possibility of having `null`s in either field from either table?

Comment: Guessing the error is "invalid character value for cast specification"

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:tsql] (SQL Server) and [tag:ibm-midrange] (DB/2).  Which is it?

Comment: Is this a linked server scenario - and which way is it from/to?

Comment: Thank you for your answers; @lc. yes this was (quickly) translated from French

Comment: @Sebastian Meine: the original error is 'caractere non admis dans la clause CAST' but there is no error number whatsoever in the interface I used

Comment: @JoeFletch : actually I did specifiy the table in the original query sorry about that. will try the other way around ie cast to char tommorrow (not at work now), thanks. and yes there may be NULL fields

Comment: @JamesA: did not intend to tag ibm-midrange...auto-completion, will remove now, thanks. it is tsql.!

Comment: First thing I would do is to see if any of the data is invalid for the cast you are attempting to do by running something like 

SELECT FieldB From TableName Where ISNUMERIC(FieldB) = 0

Comment: @Fred: actually this is good advice. problem is that I don't have the isnumeric() function. But the problem definitely comes from that as I have empty fields and maybe some alpha (I shouldnt but im not the one maintaining the db and seeing the field type is char it is probable). I tried to do a select cast(fieldB as decimal(10,0)) from tableB where fieldB not in ('',' ') [yes i know...] but still an error so there is surely something I am missing. Actually will try the other way around = cast(fieldA as char) as suggested earlier that should do if the problem is only that ? Thanks

Comment: @Imb: What DB server is your database on, version etc?

Comment: @Fred: OK I know this sounds really stupid but I was always sure it was tsql, as when I looked for help online all the functions seemed to match with what I could use, but I have a huge doubt now ! The server is AS400/IBM. I have tried the cast as char and it (almost) works ! just need to look into it a bit more but i don't have this error now

Comment: :Imb: The last time I touched AS400 was in college and that was many moons ago! If I remember correctly its DB2, TSQL is a language not a server.  However I suspect the error you are getting is because of the data, you may have to do a little data cleansing to get this working.

Comment: @Fred:  Ok thanks for that. I should be able to work around this now, at least I understand what's going on !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanks to the comments I understand that some fields that I tried to cast as decimal were not numeric - I just did it the other way around casting the decimal field as char, this works.

Thanks for your help